# Change the checkbox style in codename one

Tags: java, checkbox, codenameone

I couldn't manage it to customize the style of a checkbox component. The image for the selected state doesn't get shown when the application runs. I already set the border types to "Empty" for each relevant state. Did I miss something?

[example image for the selected state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qyfg.png)

[checkbox component in gui builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9UL7.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) please post a [mcve] and look at [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you should look at the `OnOffSwitch` component and check it out in the [component gallery](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/package-summary.html) as it looks exactly like what you are trying to accomplish.

You are customizing the components background not its state image. The state image is a special case image in the case of a check box that can be customized via theme constants and changes based on selected state. The background is unaware of those states, selected in this case is a synonym for focused...

Comment: I was aware of the `OnOffSwitch` but the image I used was just for testing purposes. I'm planning to use other images. Just for curiosity, since in the gui builder I'm able to set a "selected" or "unselected" style for components. Thus aren't those selection state dependent? When do those styles get applied? I just try to understand the concept :)

Comment: Those are applied based on focus. You can customize the image properties for the checkbox using the theme constants https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html

Comment: It seems useless, because it shows whole rectangle area when i place it on some image or black background. Any way to avoid it? (I tried to theme customizing however failed.)

Comment: It's an old component that predated a lot of the newer features in Codename One. We will need to rewrite it and should get to it as part of our UI design work. Feel free to file an RFE on that